# text disappear when setting image to navBar

Tags: ios, image, text, navbar

Im showing an image a nav bar,  but the title has disappear, why?

how to fix it?

> ```
>  - (void)viewDidLoad {
> [super viewDidLoad];
> ```
>
> UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar.png"];

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
self.navigationItem.titleView=imageView;
[imageView release];
 // self.title = @"Bio"; 
self.navigationItem.title = @"Bio";
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've replaced the title view with your image view, so the navigation bar can no longer display a title.

If you want text and an image, you'll need to add an image view with a `UILabel` subview as the titleView, and set the text of the `UILabel`.